# how can i add an image as a title, which appears in the title bar?

Tags: html

I want to know how to add an image logo as website title. for example if we open our gmail, it shows gmail logo in the title bar
how to achieve this..

```
<title>
<img src="as.jpg"></img> Hello user 
</title>
```

Comment: Hi, it's called Favicon.

Comment: Note that the [`<title>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) should only contain text content, and not markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), it should not be confused with [the title element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title), which should only contain text.

Something like this will work, assuming you've got favicon.png saved in the same directory.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

You can add a title aswell, so your outcome could be something like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Awesome title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

It's also common to use a .ico file instead, you can easily find an online converter for that.